# What headers are automatically sent by wget?

Tags: http, http-headers, wget

I know that you can manually set some headers with the `--header` option, but I want to know what headers it sends without interaction.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Using the `-d` (`--debug`) option I see it set:

```
---request begin---
GET / HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.12 (cygwin)
Accept: */*
Host: www.uml.edu
Connection: Keep-Alive

---request end---
```

Comment: Actually, the fact that `-d` prints the full headers exchange is not mentioned in the manpage. Grepping the manpage for 'header' or 'request' does _not_ turn up the `-d` option.

Comment: the `-d` option is only available if wget was compiled with debug support.

Comment: The question that brought me here was "does it send the Referer header?", the answer is yes (cookies too).